# Does Arquillian support Java EE 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian

On the official Arquillian site I found table with supported container adapters https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+adapters. There is only one Java EE 7 container and it is in category "Container adapters managed outside of the Arquillian project".
I conclude that Arquillian doesn't support Java EE 7 (yet?).
But there are presentations https://www.parleys.com/talk/testing-java-ee-applications-arquillian about testing Java EE 7. Arquillian is used. I found sources https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples and Glassfish 3.1 is used.

So does Arquillian support Java EE 7?
Why peopele use old Glassfish (Java EE 6) while testing Java EE 7?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java EE 7 is really supported by Arquillian. I'm using both Wildfly 8.x and Glassfish 4.x and it works like a charm.

Few notes:

1. I don't know why matrix you've provided is not up to date.
2. In [samples sources](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) you've linked to, GF 4.0 is used (which is Java EE 7 compatible) and also Wildfly 8.2.0.Final (which is Java EE 7-enabled too). So why do you doubt?

Comment: Because in pom.xml of this sample project I found: <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>

Comment: @guest I believe, but root pom has `<glassfish.version>4.0</glassfish.version>` and also for every single sample project you can override the version used.